# How to remove a component React has rendered via a function

Tags: reactjs

Please reference [this Codesandbox for my example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-resonance-nqj0l?file=/src/App.js)

I am having problems deleting components that get rendered via a function. Since components should not be stored in state, I store their type in an array in the parent component's state instead. A function iterates through that array to render the components. When I attempt to delete a specific component by index, React does not update the props (the index) in the component I want to keep (ie: changing the component at index 2 down to index 1). Instead, it renders the component already at that index. My Codesandbox example demonstrates this behavior.

How can I delete a component that is rendered in this way (via a function that uses the parent's state to populate props)? Is there another way I could be rendering these components?

Comment: Give each component a unique identifier. When you delete a component, find it by id and remove from the array. Don't use index because it's not persistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @MichaelRovinsky said:

> Give each component a unique identifier. When you delete a component,
> find it by id and remove from the array. Don't use index because it's
> not persistent

So, you need to use a unique identifier.

For that, you can use [react-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid).

First, I've redefined your step as:

```
export class Step {
  Id;
  Type;
  Value;
}
```

So, your default data should be like:

```
const defaultSteps = [
    { Type: ALPHA, Id: uuid(), Value: 0 },
    { Type: ALPHA, Id: uuid(), Value: 0 },
    { Type: ALPHA, Id: uuid(), Value: 0 }
  ];
```

I've also changed `Alpha` component's `index` prop with `id`.

Inside your `renderSteps` function:

```
case ALPHA:
      return (
        <Alpha
          id={step.Id}
          onChange={onValueChange}
          onDelete={index > 0 ? () => onDelete(step) : null}
          key={step.Id}
        />
      );
```

See, now both the `id` prop and `key` are the same and unique.

`onValueChange` event:

```
const onValueChange = (id, newValue) => {
    let currentSteps = [...steps];
    const step = currentSteps.filter((f) => f.Id === id)[0];
    step.Value = newValue;
    setSteps(currentSteps);
    setValues(currentSteps.map((m) => m.Value));
  };
```

So, setting your values becomes much simpler without tracing indexes.

`onDelete` event:

```
const onDelete = (step) => {
    let currentSteps = [...steps];
    const index = currentSteps.indexOf(step);
    currentSteps.splice(index, 1);
    setSteps(currentSteps);
    setValues(currentSteps.map((m) => m.Value));
  };
```

As all of your required properties are now inside single object, it's much easier to handle both `steps` and `values` state.

**Working demo** at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-shape-8sys6?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of hard for me to make sense of your code but the live demo looks clear enough.

Your state is an array and each item can be rendered as an isolated component. What you want to do is let the state flow down into your components, and wire them up to update it properly (when you click the delete key, an array item needs to be removed).

Here's how you can achieve this in a much simpler way: [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cohen-w6tq4?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Since your Item component does not have any internal state, the error I'm reporting doesn't occur. Even the solution above that I marked as correct missed the fact that the key assigned to the components (in your case, Item) should not have the index in it. It needs a unique id.

Comment: @LBecker I am not sure I follow. What's wrong with passing the props that a component needs to render itself?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with passing props. However, when props change, the values the component holds in state don't always persist. That's why I said your Item component does not reflect the issue I am seeing. Item has nothing in state (useState). Alpha generates a random number and stores it in state to demonstrate how that value does not become the new value for index 1 when index 1 is first deleted and the original index 2 becomes index 1.

Comment: @LBecker But do you really need to maintain state in your `Alpha`/`Item` components? In my opinion, that's just adding an unnecessary level of complexity.